# In Scenekit, why is there a distortion in 3d object when rendered?

Tags: graphics, 3d, blender, scenekit

In Xcode, this is how an object created in Blender and exported in DAE file looks:

[image]

Then, when I click the little play button below the image, or when I run the app and render it, it looks like this:

[image]

What can be causing this, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was produced by parenting. The torus had a parent, removing the parent avoided the distortion.